# Choosing the type of column value for indexing in mongo

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

```
document : {
     score:123
}
```

I have a field in the document called **score**(integer). I want to use a range query **db.collection.find({score: {$gte: 100, $lt: 200}})**. I have definite number of these ranges(approx 20).
Should i introduce a new field in the document to tell the type of range and then query on the indentifier of that range. Ex -

```
document: {
    score: 123,
    scoreType: "type1"
}
```

so which query is better-
1. db.collection.find({score: {$gte: 100, $lt: 200}})
2. db.collection.find({scoreType: "type1"})

In any case i will have to create an Index on either score or scoreType.
Which index would tend to perform better??

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on your situation, if you are sure the number of documents in your database will always remain the same then use scoreType.

*Keep in mind*: scoreType will be a fixed value and thus will not help when you query over different ranges i.e it might work for 100 to 200 if score type was created 
with this range in mind, but will not work for other ranges i.e for 100 to 500,(Do you plan on having a new scoreType2?) keeping flexibility in scope, this is a bad idea

Comment: My documents are always gonna increase. But the types of range that i define are gonna be definite forever. That means the column - scoreType can take up only, say 20 values depending on the score of the document.

Comment: will you always query `score: {$gte: 100, $lt: 200}` or  `score: {$gte: 200, $lt: 300}` ?

Comment: Yes. I have these fixed buckets of ranges - (100, 200) , (200,300) and so on.